# share global variables between modules

Tags: python

I have 2 python modules. In one of them there is a boolean variable which is being changed continuously (according to input).
In the second module I'm doing something according to the value of boolean variable in the first module.

I want this shared variable to be updated simultaneously but the value doesn't change since I import it the first time.
I tried to use global variables but that doesn't work too!

In a simplified way:

module1.py:

```
my_boolean = True
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == 'change':
        my_boolean = not my_boolean
```

in module2.py:

```
import module1
while True:
    print (module1.my_boolean)

#The output of print is constant and is not real-time.
```

What is the correct way to share this variable and it's update value?

Comment: You have two while True loops have you also two threads? Because otherwise your code can't work...

Comment: There are two different modules! Two different processes. Why do I need threads??!!

Comment: You Import module1 into module2 hence you have one process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a generator function. A generator is a special function that, instead of executing when called, it returns an iterator that executes the body until it comes to a `yield` statement. Any function with a `yield` statement is a generator.

module1.py:

```
# This function will not execute until the for loop requests a value.
def getBools():
    my_boolean = True
    while True:
        a = input()
        if a == 'change':
            my_boolean = not my_boolean
        # Pause execution and hand this value to the for loop.
        yield my_boolean
```

module2.py:

```
import module1

for b in module1.getBools():
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works - maybe that helps you out

Module 4:

```
my_boolean = True
```

Module 1:

```
import module4

def change_value():
    a = input()
    if a == 'change':
        module4.my_boolean = not module4.my_boolean
```

Module 2:

```
import module4

def print_current_value():
    print (module4.my_boolean)

#The output of print is constant and is not real-time.
```

Module 3:

```
from module1 import change_value
from module2 import print_current_value

while True:
    print_current_value()
    change_value()
```

Running module 3 shows that the modules are sharing the variable of module 4.

```
True
change
False
change
True
asdf
True
asdf
True
```